utilize nested loop in multiple parameters when utilizing API calls
I want to utilize looping mechanism within PowerQuery in Excel.
There is a limit of 1000 records to be retrieve for each call so I need to get offset parameter to loop through increment of 1000.  In addition, I need to use values from GroupID column from GroupTable to be implemented within the API call as well so each group value will retrieve the data.
For more clarification, I have specific API link that I want to utilize the loops with two parameters
ex. www.api.com/user?offset=\[loop\]&groupId=\[loop2\]
so for sample value of GroupId = {"ABC", "DEF", "GHI"}, ABC has 2000 rows, DEF has 2000 rows, GHI 4000 rows, I want to retrieve all 8000 records.
I was able to incorporate offset, but not sure how to implement groupdid portion:
let 
    SourceURL = "www.api.com/user",
    InitialResponse = Json.Document(Web.Contents(SourceURL)), 
    Total = InitialResponse[total],
    BatchSize = 1000, 
    NumberOfCalls = Number.RoundUp(Total / BatchSize), 
    ListOfOffsets = List.Number(0, NumberOfCalls, BatchSize), 
    ListGroup = List.Transform(UserGroup, each UserGroup.id (group, _)), 
    FetchPage = (Offset) => 
        let 
            Response = Json.Document(Web.Contents(SourceURL, [Query=[#"offset"=Text.From(Offset)]])), 
            Data = Response[results] 
        in
            Data, 
    CombineData = List.Combine(AllData), 
    OutputTable = Table.FromList(CombineData, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error) 
in 
    OutputTable


https://gorilla.bi/power-query/list-generate-api-calls/

When I get stuck on stuff like this, I like to use tables to be able to see what I'm doing and then refactor once I've got it right.
Also, I don't think the ListGroup step is correct, and I don't see how you know a total count per list group.
But let's say you can get to a table of group ids and totals... You can turn that into a table with one row per page, and then process that.
let
    SourceURL = "www.api.com/user",
    BatchSize = 1000,

    // replace how we get GroupsAndTotals with your own stuff
    GroupsAndTotals = #table(
        type table [GroupId = text, Total = Int64.Type],
        {
            {"ABC", 2000},
            {"DEF", 2000},
            {"GHI", 8000}
        }
    ),

    // Add a list of offsets per GroupID
    #"Added Offset" = Table.AddColumn(
        GroupsAndTotals,
        "Offset",
        each List.Numbers(
            0,
            Number.RoundUp([Total] / BatchSize),
            BatchSize
        ),
        type list
    ),

    // Expand the list into new rows
    #"Expanded Offset" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Offset", "Offset"),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Offset",{{"Offset", Int64.Type}}),

    // Now we can get the query variables per call we want to make
    #"Added QueryVariables" = Table.AddColumn(
        #"Changed Type",
        "QueryVariables",
        each [
            offset = Text.From([Offset]),
            groupId = [GroupId]
        ],
        type record
    ),

    // Now we can get results per page...
    #"Added Results" = Table.AddColumn(
        #"Added QueryVariables",
        "Results",
        each Web.Contents(
            SourceURL,
            [
                Query = [QueryVariables]
            ]
        )
    )
in
    #"Added Results"

You can then process each page of results, into a table, and use Table.Combine to merge it all together.
